# Make Nautilus as default file browser

Tags: unity, nautilus

I had set Nemo as default file manager on my Unity desktop. I want return to old configurations and Nautilus be my default file manager. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This will reset Nautilus as the default:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

(the last one is to refresh the desktop)

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and paste this line.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/nemo /usr/bin/nemo.back && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/nemo
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: why neg vote ? that answer will help.

Comment: I don't know who voted as negative. I am voting as positive to recover its effect. Your solution is correct but remove Nemo as file manager, I want use it when I need it. I want change default manager only.

Comment: Hmmm I can imagine that linking nautilus with nemo might not be the correct method. Not that I am the one (I made it +1 ;)).

Comment: It wont remove nemo . nemo is there but its moved to nemo.back name